# instance creation failed for ViewClient Object in Jython

Tags: android, jython

I am using monkeyrunner for android device testing through Jython program.But i am getting the  error while creating ViewClient object.The error details shown in below:

Exception: Cannot start View server.
This only works on emulator and devices running developer versions.
Does hierarchyviewer work on your device ?

when i typed hierarchyviewer command from the command line, i am getting the followings:

```
D:\Telus\Pyton Programs>hierarchyviewer
The standalone version of hieararchyviewer is deprecated.
Please use Android Device Monitor (tools/monitor.bat) instead.
04:57:24 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server version from device 644276034934
04:57:24 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to get view server protocol version from device 644276034934
04:57:27 E/hierarchyviewer: Unable to debug device 644276034934
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the limitation of the AVC . AndroidViewClient is for emulator and running developer versions only you can not test your application on real devices with AVC. you can find more info For hiearachyviewer  on this http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-ui.html